# Parameters Client Side XSLT

Tags: php, xml, xslt

What would be the equivalent of this server side version to set xslt param, but with client side?

```
$xslt = new XSLTProcessor();
$xslt->setParameter('', 'value', $_REQUEST['value']); // param 1
$xslt->setParameter('', 'column', $_REQUEST['column']); // param 2
$xslt->setParameter('', 'page', $_REQUEST['page']); // param 3
$xslDoc = new DOMDocument();
$xslDoc->load('nginxSearchPaginated.xsl', LIBXML_NOCDATA);
$xslt->importStylesheet($xslDoc);
echo $xslt->transformtoXML($xmlDom1);
```

All the parameters need to come from the REQUEST just like above.

This is what I have tried so far client side:

```
$xslt = $xmlDom1->createProcessingInstruction('xml-stylesheet', 'type="text/xsl" href="clientSideFewSearch.xsl"');
$xslt->setParameter('', 'value', $_REQUEST['value']); // param 1
$xslt->setParameter('', 'column', $_REQUEST['column']); // param 2
$xslt->setParameter('', 'page', $_REQUEST['page']); // param 3
$xmlDom1->insertBefore($xslt,$xmlRoot1);
echo $xmlDom1->saveXML();
```

Without the parameters the code does work, but I need the parameters for pagination.

Any help would be great thanks

Comment: You're assuming the client side has the necessary software installed to do the transformation.  Why do you need the transformation to happen client-side?

Comment: I was asked to by my lecturer.

Comment: I've accomplished everything server side but I need to repeat the exercise on the client

Comment: Isn't the `href` resolved relative to the URI from which the document was loaded? In that case the stylesheet is being sent from the server as well.  You could try adding the parameters to the URI, as in `clientSideFewSearch.xsl?value=...&column=...&page=...`. Although I can find nothing in the spec that says this _should_ work, it's what I'd try first.

Comment: Like you use PHP and XSLT on the server, you would need to use Javascript and XSLT on the client, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XSLTProcessor

Comment: That does not really make sense you're using the server side xslt processor and you output the pi to trigger xslt processing on the client. Who should use the parameters? At the moment you're providing them to the server side xslt processor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are essentially two ways of running XSLT "client-side" (by which I assume you mean, in the browser). The first way is to use the XSLT 1.0 processor that comes built in to nearly all browsers. The other is to use Saxon-JS, which is an XSLT 3.0 processor written in Javascript.

If you use the built-in XSLT 1.0 processor you can activate it either by means of an `<?xml-stylesheet?>` processing instruction in the XML file (in which case there is no way of providing parameters, other than having the stylesheet read the required information from some XML document); or you can invoke the transformation from Javascript typically using the Sarissa API, which has a method to set parameters:

```
XSLTProcessor.prototype.setParameter = function(nsURI, name, value){...}
```

If you want to use Saxon-JS instead (which not only offers XSLT 3.0, but also allows the stylesheet to be interactive, processing user-initiated events as they occur), then you can supply parameters using the `stylesheetParams` option - see the documentation at http://www.saxonica.com/saxon-js/documentation/index.html#!api/transform (which is itself a Saxon-JS application).